# Vague MVC and Castle Windsor question. Sorry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have inheritted some code in which the MVC Controller classes all get their constructors called by Castle....DefaultProxyFactory.Create() somewhere along the line (the call stack drops out to the `<external code>`, which isn't helping.)

So, basically, how would I go about finding out where Castle is being told how to call the constructors of my Controllers?

I am very new to Castle, Windsor and MicroKernel, etc, and not a master of ASP's MVC.

Many thanks for any pointers - sorry about the vagueness,

Matt.

Comment: You mean ASP.NET MVC? Check your ControllerFactory. If you want the details of how components in Windsor are created and how constructors are selected see these links: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-components-are-created.ashx http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-constructor-is-selected.ashx?HL=constructor

Comment: do you have any problem/exception in particular, or do you just want to understand how Windsor/MVC works?

Comment: I have no actual exceptions, but I have a fairly large solution to understand and it involves a lot of DI, IoC, Windsor, NHibernate, etc and understand the architecture before solving/altering code is, I think, where I should be focussing now.

Comment: do you have *multiple* constructors per controller?

Comment: No, I also can't find any uses of ControllerFactory in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx) explains the lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC controller in detail, including when the ControllerFactory is called and how to hook up an IoC container. StructureMap is used in this particular article, but any IoC container can be used in its place.

In your ControllerFactory, Windsor picks up and instantiates the actual controller as explained in the articles Krzysztof commented:

- [How components are created](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-components-are-created.ashx)
- [How the component constructor is selected](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-constructor-is-selected.ashx?HL=constructor)

If you see a reference to `DefaultProxyFactory.Create(...)` in your stack trace it means that a proxy is being created. Windsor's default proxy factory is [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html). You can learn about it in [Krzysztof's tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial.aspx).